# How to add jQuery code on a specific page only

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

In my ASP.NET Core Code first project developed using `ASP.NET Cor Web Application (.NET Core) template` how can I add, for example, following jQuery code on a specific view, say, `test.cshtml` so that it is included only on a page using this view. I'm using `VS2015-Update3.1`. Only those familiar with the folder structure of such a project in VS2015 can probably answer.

**NOTE**: I'm trying to add following script inline and not as a file.

```
$('.list-group-item').click(function(e){ 
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: are you trying to add it inline, or as a file?

Comment: @Mike_G Good question. I'm trying to add it inline. I've added a Note in my post based on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `_Layout.cshtml` file that comes with the standard project template calls `RenderSection()` near the very bottom:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

This tells the ViewEngine to insert a section called `scripts` (if present) from the rendered View (which gets inserted exactly in the place where `RenderBody()` is called.

```
// Test.cshtml

...
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Item-1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item-2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Item-3</li>
</ul>
...

@section scripts
{
  <script>
    $('.list-group-item').click(function(e){ 
      e.stopPropagation();
    })
  </script>
}
```

So just define the section in your view and it will get inserted in the layout in the designated place.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your solution. However, the jQuery code suggested by Taras Kumpanenko and Juan Ferreras in my another question  posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38857469/1232087) is not working. Maybe it has something to do with their code or me using it wrong. Someone may help. Since you answered my this post, I'll mark it as an answer.